# Leaving a job - is there generally a gap between health insurance and COBRA

Tags: united-states, insurance

COBRA exists as a stop-gap between insurance coverages, from one employer to the next.  If I quit my job to go mountain climbing, and tell HR that yes, I want to sign up for COBRA (and sign the form), am I covered continuously, or is there generally a gap while the forms are mailed in to the government, processed, etc?

Comment: Isn't this a perfect question for your HR department?

Comment: @JoelEtherton sometimes it's not good to give them advance notice of your plans

Comment: COBRA is not a company policy, it is Federal law.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

COBRA is retroactive, as long as you signup by the deadline. The best part for most job changes is that the deadline is after the new insurance kicks in. An even better feature is it takes weeks to get the paperwork to you so if the insurance gaps is measured in days or a few weeks you can't even decide until after the new insurance kicks in.

So if during the gap you have no medical issues, you never have to signup and pay the large COBRA rates. But if you suffer a major illness or injury you can decide if the increased rates are a bargain.

> I want to sign up for COBRA (and sign the form), am I covered
> continuously, or is there generally a gap while the forms are mailed
> in to the government, processed, etc?

[Yes it is retroactive](https://www.cms.gov/CCIIO/Programs-and-Initiatives/Other-Insurance-Protections/cobra_qna)

> Q14: How do I elect COBRA?
>
> Qualified beneficiaries must notify the plan administer of their
> election according to the instructions laid out in the election
> notice.  Qualified beneficiaries must be given an election period of
> at least 60 days during which each qualified beneficiary may choose
> whether to elect COBRA coverage.  This period is measured from the
> later of the date of the qualifying event or the date the COBRA
> election notice is provided.  COBRA coverage is retroactive if elected
> and paid for by the qualified beneficiary.

During the [COVID-19 emergency the deadline has been extended](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/hr-topics/benefits/pages/dol-temporarily-extends-cobra-deadlines-coronavirus.aspx):

> The rule extends most COBRA deadlines to beyond the "Outbreak Period,"
> which it defines as March 1, 2020, to 60 days after the end of the
> declared COVID-10 national emergency, or another date if provided by
> the agencies in future guidance. If the emergency declaration expires
> as written on June 29, 2020, the Outbreak Period will end on August
> 28, 2020, for instance.
>
> The COBRA election period. Under COBRA, employees and dependents who
> lose active coverage as a result of a qualifying event, such as
> termination of employment or reduction of hours, normally have 60 days
> to elect continuation of coverage after receiving a COBRA election
> notice. Under the rule, the 60-day timeframe doesn't start until the
> end of the Outbreak Period.